# Workday - SOAP API - Create_Requisition_Request SOAP Payload

Tags: soap, soapui, workday-api

I am working on Workday SOAP API. Using SOAP API - I am trying to create a Job Requisition (Create_Requisition_Request) and  I am struggling with what valid values could be for each attribute and element. Could anyone please help me with some sample requests or point me to the link where I could get the valid values for each elements and attributes. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have wsdl?

Comment: Yes I have it -  Here  is the link to the WSDL - https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Recruiting/v29.1/Recruiting.html

Comment: In order to use right values, you need to refer xsd file which available there in the link you have provided.

Comment: xsd would only give me the value to be entered for the "type" attribute, but to input the value of it, I need to value from the workday system, which I am unable to fetch. For Example, I got the key WID but how do I fetch its value? any pointers on it?

Answer (score 1):

I have filled the xml payload with minimal information. you can add or remove some fields.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bsvc="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <bsvc:Create_Requisition_Request bsvc:version="v27.2">
            <bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
                <bsvc:Auto_Complete>true</bsvc:Auto_Complete>
                <bsvc:Run_Now>true</bsvc:Run_Now>
                <bsvc:Comment_Data>
                    <bsvc:Comment>Create Job Requisition using WWS</bsvc:Comment>
                </bsvc:Comment_Data>
            </bsvc:Business_Process_Parameters>
            <bsvc:Create_Job_Requisition_Data>
                <bsvc:Position_Restriction_Reference>
                    <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Position_ID">Your Position ID eg P-00300</bsvc:ID>
                </bsvc:Position_Restriction_Reference>
                <bsvc:Number_of_Openings>1</bsvc:Number_of_Openings>
                <bsvc:Job_Requisition_Data>
                    <bsvc:Job_Requisition_ID>MY-REQ-001</bsvc:Job_Requisition_ID>
                    <bsvc:Job_Posting_Title>Software Engineer</bsvc:Job_Posting_Title>
                    <bsvc:Recruiting_Start_Date>2018-01-01</bsvc:Recruiting_Start_Date>
                    <bsvc:Target_Hire_Date>2018-01-01</bsvc:Target_Hire_Date>
                    <bsvc:Job_Profile_Reference>
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Job_Profile_ID">Enter Job profile ID (it should be in your tenant)</bsvc:ID>
                    </bsvc:Job_Profile_Reference>
                    <bsvc:Worker_Type_Reference>                        
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Worker_Type_ID">Employee</bsvc:ID>
                    </bsvc:Worker_Type_Reference>
                    <bsvc:Worker_Sub-Type_Reference>
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Employee_Type_ID">Regular</bsvc:ID>
                    </bsvc:Worker_Sub-Type_Reference>
                    <bsvc:Primary_Location_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="nimborum in">
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Location_ID">Toronto_site</bsvc:ID>
                    </bsvc:Primary_Location_Reference>
                    <bsvc:Position_Time_Type_Reference bsvc:Descriptor="animos et temperat">
                        <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Position_Time_Type_ID">Full_time</bsvc:ID>
                    </bsvc:Position_Time_Type_Reference>
                    <bsvc:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>40</bsvc:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours>
                </bsvc:Job_Requisition_Data>
            </bsvc:Create_Job_Requisition_Data>
        </bsvc:Create_Requisition_Request>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks Hikmat for taking out time to post your comment. I tried out the XML structure you have shared but my concern is since I am new to Workday I am not sure from where will I get the values for the reference fields like in the above XML structure, I am stuck at          '<bsvc:Job_Profile_Reference>
 <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Job_Profile_ID">Enter Job profile ID (it should be in your tenant)</bsvc:ID>
 </bsvc:Job_Profile_Reference>'
Could you please help me understand or point me to the link where I can get information about how I could get the valid values for each elements and attributes.

Comment: how about skype call, pleas share your contact details

Comment: @Hikmat I am trying submit a customer but I am getting  "Country Reference is required unless address is being deleted". The Country_reference ID I used was ISO_3166-1_Alpha-2_Code. I have also tried removing the country reference when submitting customer but to no avail.

Comment: @SamarRizvi can you share more details